# How to assign Custom content type to sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I create "News" content type which is Inherited from article CT. and I want to add this newly created CT to sharepoint page.

Answer (score 1):

I guess by Article content type you mean, **Article Page**.

To create pages with your Newly created content type, just add a  **page library** and assign your **News** content type to it.

Now you can create pages with it.  *Also you may select this **News** content type as default content type for that page library*